# How can I create pre-defined attribute :day

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I make attribute :day with predefined values (monday, tuesday etc.) to later choose them in form while creating new event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it an integer that holds a value from 0 to 6.

On the form you'd do

```
select("event", "day", %w(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday).each_with_index.map{|x,i|[x, i]}, { include_blank: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for enumerables. In Rails, a few gems such as [**enumerize**](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) are available.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'enumerize'

# app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  enumerize :day, in: %w[monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday]
end

# app/views/events/_form.html.erb
<%- form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :day, Event.day.options %>
<% end %>
```

Another great gem in that field is [assignable_values](https://github.com/makandra/assignable_values).

Comment: Extra question: does adding values 2..5 as enum makes sense ?

Comment: Enums can be stored as string or integers, but I find strings to be more convenient. For a `day` the range might work just fine and not be too confusing.